# Getting an error about a ", but there is no "

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I'm writing some assembler code for the ATmega8, and I am getting a rather weird error.

Here is an example-ized sample of the line in which the error is happening:

```
ldi A, B%C
```

Where `A`, `B`, and `C` are defined like this at the top of my code:

```
.DEF A = r1
.DEF B = r0
.EQU C = 15
```

This is the error I am getting(this originally was a table):

> **Description**: syntax error, unexpected "
>
> **File**: test.asm
>
> **Line**: 120
>
> **Col**: 0
>
> **Project**: Testing

What is strange is that there is not a single `"` in my entire code. However, I has suspicions that the `"` could be coming from the included file `m8def.inc`. 
This was assembled using Atmel Studio's assembler.

Comment: What do you even want to do? `r0%15` makes no sense. Also, which assembler are you using?

Comment: @Jester Why do you need to know why I need to find out what the value in `r0` mod 15 is? I will add the assembler.

Comment: The error is not about a `"` character. It is concerned with an unprintable character in column 0 of line 120. This is causing the rest of the error message to not appear, including the trailing `"` that should follow the offending character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do you need to know why I need to find out what the value in r0
>   mod 15 is?

I needeed to know that you wanted *to find out what the value in r0 mod 15 is*... That's not the way to do it, since `ldi` can only load compile time constants. To do `mod 15` you need a division, but atmega8 doesn't have that. You could do repeated subtraction or magic number multiply.

However, given your additional information about `B` being a counter, the simplest solution is to keep a `mod 15` counter in `A`, which gets reset to `0` when it hits `15`.

Comment: `A` will not always be >= `r16`. `B` is a counter that starts at 0, and by your code, it is moved into `A`. And, I'm a little confused by the "EDIT:" part: are you saying that the code you have shown only does `%16`, and not `%15`?

Comment: Yeah the code I showed does `%16`. If you have a loop with a counter, the easiest way is to keep a separate `%15` counter which simply resets back to 0 when it hits 15.

Comment: This is just a side and unrelated question, but why did you choose `r16` as an example register? I've seen it used in other examples before, but I don't understand why you wouldn't start at the beginning and use `r0`.

Comment: Because some instructions, such as the `andi` I used and the `ldi` you used, only allow registers starting from `r16`.